# Android - How to use Android Asset Packaging Tool?

Tags: android, aapt

I want to use `aapt.exe` to stop compress my `database.db` file when compile my android app. I run terminal (Mac OS) and type:

```
aapt -0 db
```

It throws the error:

```
ERROR: Unknown command '-0'
Android Asset Packaging Tool
```

I am using android sdk v20.0.1. Did I make any mistake?

Answer (score 7):

### AFAIK:

- This tool allows you to view, create, and update Zip-compatible
  archives (zip, jar, apk). It can also compile resources into binary
  assets .
- aapt that Android Asset Packaging Tool in the SDK tools / directory
  of the tool you can view, create, update the ZIP format document
  attachments (zip, jar, apk). resource files can also be compiled into
  a binary file.
- Though you probably won't often use aapt directly, build scripts and
  IDE plugins can utilize this tool to package the apk file that
  constitutes an Android application.
- Even though you may not directly use aapt tool, but the build scripts
  and IDE plug-in will use this tool packaged apk file constitutes an
  Android application.

### FYI:

- **Linux or Mac OS X:**

  - open a terminal, go to the tools / directory,
  - run the command. / Aapt
- **Windows:**

  - open command prompt and go to to the tools / directory,
  - execute the command aapt.exe

### aapt Commands:

- click [here](http://z987987.blogspot.in/2011/12/aapt-android-asset-packaging-tool.html) to learn aapt commands

Comment: What tools directory? This says the same http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/android/android-4.0/out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check/guide/developing/tools/aapt.html but dont know where /tools is or which /tools folder it means.

Comment: it'd be inside android sdk.

Answer (score 5):

> **aapt is a generic Android asset package tool that be used as:**

**"aapt list" -** Listing contents of a ZIP, JAR or APK file.
**"aapt dump" -** Dumping specific information from an APK file.
**"aapt package" -** Packaging Android resources.
**"aapt remove" -** Removing files from a ZIP, JAR or APK file.
**"aapt add" -** Adding files to a ZIP, JAR or APK file.
**"aapt crunch" -** Crunching PNG files.

Comment: What "crunching png files" does?

Comment: Crunching means converting large size PNG to reduced PNG. https://aaptpatch.codeplex.com This is where I found it.

Comment: Crunching is a compress the raster images when creating a build as like :-crunch:
[crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: usr/build/apk_file/res